# Unity skybox rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, skybox

I am currently making a unity game where I will be able to navigate from one 360 degrees panorama to another.

I have added the pictures and made the texture size as a cube and mapped to the latitude-longitude layout. I have made skybox material and loaded the image into it.

Now the problem I am facing here is-

Whenever I load the skyboxes, it looks to some other direction instead of the original orientation of the image. I could fix it by changing the skybox rotation to 100. Since I have planned to add around 100 pictures, I do not want them to fix each on of them manually.

All of the pictures were downloaded from google streetview.

Desperately in need of help!!

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com should be a better place to ask such a question that seems to have nothing to do with coding.

Comment: Do you need 100 rotation on each picture or different for each picture?

Comment: Hristo Unfortunately rotations are very random in all the pictures.